# How do I know which partitions I can safely remove on Windows 10?

Tags: partitioning, dropbox, onedrive, google-drive, virtual-drive

I'm using desktop apps for Google Drive, OneDrive and Dropbox, which all store files on my computer.

Google Drive used a virtual drive for its file, until I changed the *Google Drive streaming location* to a folder on my computer instead. When I did that, that folder was populated with files, and the virtual drive that used to host those files became unreachable, as expected. However, when I look in the Windows *Disk Management* app, the partition that I thought was designated for that virtual drive (because it takes up 15.83 GB of space, and the free version of Google Drive only allows you to store 15 GB) is still there, along with a bunch of other partitions that I don't know what they are for; none of them have drive letters and all of them are said to have only (100%) free space (see image).

[image]

My questions are:

1. How do I know which of these partitions are used, and which are unused and can be safely removed? If the 15.83 GB partition was used by Google Drive, I guess I can remove it, but how do I know for sure that the partition isn't used by some other application?
2. Is there some way to tell which drives (or virtual drives) the partitions that lack drive letters are mapped to (if they are mapped to any) or vice versa?

Comment: Better add a screenshot of Disk Management. And what is "a virtual drive"?

Comment: Look in Disk Management.   Windows 10 natively build 3 partitions. UEFI, Recovery and Data.  Anything above that is not a Windows issue, but is something you did. Review what you might have done and delete whatever you do not need.

Comment: @harrymc Under Google Drive _Preferences_->_Setting_->_Google Drive streaming location_, you can choose "Drive letter", which has the description "Stream Google Drive files to a virtual drive on your computer".

Comment: With a screenshot of Disk Management we can give some advise, but in general all these small partitions have their own function and are necessary. They are anyway too small to bother about. You should only ask about partitions whose size is measured in gigabytes.

Comment: @harrymc I have updated the question with an image.

Comment: @John Yes, but how do I know what I don't need (that's kind of the gist of my question)?

Comment: You need to review your partitions to see what you need.  My systems keep to the Windows partitions.

Comment: @John What do you mean by review your partitions? How do I do that?

Comment: See what apps are using the Non-Windows partitions. They are only there because some app created them. I can't see from here what that is.

Comment: It appears that you may have reinstalled Windows 10 multiple times creating multiple extra partitions.  I saw a similar thing on one old machine I have (10 years of use)

Comment: @John And how do I see what apps are using the non-windows partitions?

Comment: Probably what you need to do is back up what you need, format, delete all partitions, reinstall Windows and set up what you need. Much will go away.

Answer (score 1):

A partition that doesn't have a drive-letter is in general inaccessible
to "normal" applications, and you have three such unexplained partitions
whose size are measured in dozens of gigabytes.

There is an excellent chance that they are unused, but no certainty
that some installed application is not doing strange things.

The only real way to know  is to take a backup of the disk, delete the
partitions, and check for some days/weeks that your applications are still
functioning correctly.

I note that if deleting these partitions does turn out to be harmless,
you would still need to compact their areas, because the deletion will
create two "holes" in the disk that cannot be merged except by moving
the partitions.

One example of a free product is
[AOMEI Backupper Free](https://www.aomeitech.com/ab/standard.html).
You should take a complete backup of the entire disk (not of individual
partitions).
I would also suggest to create the
[AOMEI Bootable Media](https://www.ubackup.com/help/create-bootable-disk.html)
as a precaution.